# GCM Android API Key With Certificates Doesn't Work

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have Push notifications implemented with GCM. I've got a sender ID and an Android API key that allows any app to use. With these settings I have no issues.

I want to add a little bit more security and only allow *my* apps to use the API key.
I've noticed that I can add a `SHA1` certificate fingerprint of my keystore to limit the API key usage. When I do this however I don't receive any notifications anymore.

Nothing blows up in the app code so I'm wondering if I am missing a server setting.
What are some things I can do to troubleshoot this and get it running?